# MySQL: Copy data from TableA:FieldA to TableB:FieldB matching common UID field

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I didn't see this exact question asked. Most people seem to want to sync. I just need a one-time copy.

MySQL version is 5.5.35.

In my MySQL database I need to one-time copy data from TableA:FieldA to TableB:FieldB while matching a common UID field — TableA:UID and TableB:UID are the related fields.

More specifically I am copying Employee ID from one table to a different field in another table, and both tables have Contact ID in common. So obviously I need TableA:UID=1's Employee Number to appear in TableB on the correct row where TableB:UID=1.

Thanks.

UPDATED: Tested the solution, got an error 1442

```
UPDATE civicrm_value_member_fields_1
SET civicrm_value_member_fields_1.aft_id_43 = 
(SELECT civicrm_contact.external_identifier FROM civicrm_contact 
WHERE civicrm_contact.id = civicrm_value_member_fields_1.entity_id)
```

alt version of the above:

```
UPDATE `civicrm_value_member_fields_1`
SET `aft_id_43` = 
(SELECT `external_identifier` FROM `civicrm_contact`
WHERE `id` = `entity_id`)
```

both error 1442:

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'civicrm_contact' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example should help.

```
create table A(id int,cid int);
create table B(id int,cid int);

insert into A values(6,1); 
insert into A values(7,2); 
insert into A values(8,3); 
insert into A values(9,4);

insert into B(cid) values(1);
insert into B(cid) values(3);
insert into B(cid) values(4);
```

Table A

```
| ID | CID |
|----|-----|
|  6 |   1 |
|  7 |   2 |
|  8 |   3 |
|  9 |   4 |
```

Table B

```
|     ID | CID |
|--------|-----|
| (null) |   1 |
| (null) |   3 |
| (null) |   4 |
```

The `UPDATE` query will update `B's id` field referring `A's id` field.

```
update B set B.id = (select A.id from A where A.cid = B.cid);
```

Table B

```
| ID | CID |
|----|-----|
|  6 |   1 |
|  8 |   3 |
|  9 |   4 |
```

Comment: Why "create table A(id int,cid int);" The two tables already exist. And I'm not following why it needs three or four repetitions in the insert commands. What does the "1,1" do, are where would you recommend I research this?

Comment: I tested your usecase with this example and i want you to apply the same logic for your problem. And those data are sample data. cid is the `contact id` based on which we need to update. I have edited to answer to add more clarity. hope that helps

Comment: Oh I see. This isn't a solution, it's a demonstration. That's why you are creating tables and inserting demo data. That wasn't clear.

Comment: Can you provide the `sqlfiddle` link of the schema, some sample data and the query you tried?

Comment: I added the query and actual table and field names in the question above, after the word UPDATED. I also tested three other variations on the query based on other Stackoverflow answers, and all failed.

Comment: I made an sqlfiddle, but I'm not sure it's correct: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aca211/1

Comment: It works on the fiddle. But when copy-pasted into the SQL tab in PHPMydmin, i get error "#1442 - Can't update table 'civicrm_contact' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger."

Answer (score 0):

The error can be sidestepped by first creating a temporary table - it will have all the data you need but not have the functions/triggers that impede the step.

Also, once the table is set then a JOIN statement is a more efficient representation of the action and should run more quickly as well.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE contact_dupe SELECT id, external_identifier FROM civicrm_contact;

UPDATE civicrm_value_member_fields_1 AS cs
JOIN contact_dupe AS cd ON cd.id=cs.entity_id
SET cs.aft_id_43=cc.external_identifier;
```